# How to center sidebar text and icons in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, centering, text-align

I'm trying to center both the text and icons within my website's sidebar, but my existing CSS `text-align: center;` isn't working. Here's the relevant code and screenshots:

[image]

How to convert it to like this one example below:

[image]

**Specific Questions:**

- Can you identify why `text-align: center;` isn't working in this context?
- What's the best CSS approach to achieve the centering of both text and icons within the sidebar?

**Code:**

**CSS**

```
/* sidebar starts here*/
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 260px;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    background: #df7f27;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.sidebar ul li {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
.sidebar ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.sidebar ul li a i {
    min-width: 60px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="topbar">
            <div class="logo">
                <h2>Pomodone</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search here">
                <label for="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
            <div class="user">
                <img src="img/user.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i>
                        <div>Dashboard</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i>
                        <div>Students</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i>
                        <div>Teachers</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                        <div>Employees</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>
                        <div>Analytics</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i>
                        <div>Earnings</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                        <div>Settings</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
                        <div>Help</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Before anything first understand how the icons `www.fontawesome.com` works.

*There's only one simple thing to understand that is:*

###### That the < i > tag you used here is getting commented out and a svg is been loaded to your code above the tag

```html
<i class="sidebar-icon fas fa-user-graduate"></i>
```

> #### Solution

*Just add these Properties to your html*

- ###### Padding-left: 30px or as per your requirement;
- ###### Justify-content: flex-start;

```css
.sidebar ul li a {
  width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 30px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center
}

.sidebar ul li a i {
    min-width: 60px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

*New Class to be Added for svg*

- ###### Added a fixed width for svg.
- ###### Margin-right to align the test in the same line

```css
.sidebar ul li a svg{
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 25px !important;
}
```

##### Run this Code

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}
.topbar{
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 10fr 0.4fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.logo h2{
    color: #df7f27;
}

.search{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    justify-self: center;
}

.search input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    
}
.search label {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.search i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.user{
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.user img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; 
}

/* sidebar starts here*/
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 260px;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    background: #df7f27;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.sidebar ul li {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    display:  flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.sidebar ul li a {
  width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 30px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center
}

.sidebar ul li a i {
    min-width: 60px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
.sidebar ul li a svg{
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 25px !important;
}
```

```html
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-rOA1PnstxnOBLzCLMcre8ybwbTmemjzdNlILg8O7z1lUkLXozs4DHonlDtnE7fpc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="topbar">
            <div class="logo">
                <h2>Pomodone</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search here">
                <label for="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
            <div class="user">
                <img src="img/user.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i>
                        <div>Dashboard</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i>
                        <div>Students</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i>
                        <div>Teachers</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                        <div>Employees</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>
                        <div>Analytics</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i>
                        <div>Earnings</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                        <div>Settings</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
                        <div>Help</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using flex box and then doing justify-content to be space-between or space-evenly

Answer (score 1):

You should do two things:

1. Add a new class to every icon in your sidebar, for instance:

```html
<i class="sidebar-icon fas fa-user-graduate"></i>
```

2. Style that class by adding horizontal margin. Adjust the pixels as you see fit.

```css
.sidebar-icon {
  width: 1.5em !important; /* Prevent uneven width of icons */
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

This is the result

[image: Example result]

Answer (score 1):

i see your problem you just simply need to add some css **justify-content:center;** , you use display flex that;s why text-align is not working,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-rOA1PnstxnOBLzCLMcre8ybwbTmemjzdNlILg8O7z1lUkLXozs4DHonlDtnE7fpc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>pomodone.app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="topbar">
            <div class="logo">
                <h2>Pomodone</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search here">
                <label for="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
            <div class="user">
                <img src="img/user.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i>
                        <div>Dashboard</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i>
                        <div>Students</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i>
                        <div>Teachers</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                        <div>Employees</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>
                        <div>Analytics</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd"></i>
                        <div>Earnings</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                        <div>Settings</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
                        <div>Help</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
}
.topbar{
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 10fr 0.4fr 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.logo h2{
    color: #df7f27;
}

.search{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    justify-self: center;
}

.search input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    
}
.search label {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.search i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.user{
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.user img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; 
}

/* sidebar starts here*/
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 260px;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    background: #df7f27;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar ul {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.sidebar ul li {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
}
.sidebar ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* my chnages here */
   justify-content:center;
}

.sidebar ul li a i {
    min-width: 60px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.sidebar ul li a i {
    min-width: 60px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Checkout my code, Hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.menuitem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  
}
```

change the div display to flex and try this.
please inform that I put `menuitem` to all the div class names.

Answer (score 1):

try to add float and margin to the icons

.sidebar ul li a i {
float:left;
margin:0 5px
}